# Issue with long long calculation

Tags: c

I have code that loops through numbers and creates the character array representation of that integer. So for a number like 1234 I get an array that looks like {'1', '2', '3', '4'}

Part of the code is shown below:

```
do {
   //print here
     c[i++] = (char)(((int)'0')+(num - (num/10)*10 ));
} while ((num = num/10) != 0);
```

I am having an issue when it comes to large data types like long long int: 18446612134627563776

I printed the values in the loop are:

```
18446612134627563776
18446730879801352832
18446742754318731738
...
18446744073709551615
```

The values should be

```
18446612134627563776
1844661213462756377
184466121346275637
...
18
1
```

The strange thing is that the loop terminates. The last printed value is `18446744073709551615 != 0`, so not sure why it terminated there. I think its some issue with the data type that i am not doing right.

This is the print statement:

```
printk("long=%llu sec=%llu , char=%c\n", num, (num/10)*10, (char)(((int)'0')+((num - (num/10)*10 ))));
```

Comment: Have you checked the sizes of your numbers versus the maximum sizes of the data types designed to hold them?

Comment: What sense does `(num/10)*10` ?

Comment: It's another way to write `num - (num % 10)`, @Zaffy.

Comment: The size of the number as shown above is 20 digits. when I printed sizeof(long long) i got 8, I am guessing 8 bytes?

Comment: @DanielFischer num - (num % 10) did not work, I am trying the floor approach below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `long long int`: 18446612134627563776

`long long int` is a signed type, usually 64 bits wide, with the maximal representable number

```
2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807
```

Your value is larger than that, and overflows, probably to

```
2^63 - 18446612134627563776 = -131939081987840
```

The printed values are

```
2^64 + (-131939081987840)/(10^k)
```

Change the type to `unsigned long long` to get the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine.  The problem is that the type of `num` is signed (i.e. just `long long`).  Change it to (`unsigned long long`) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the modulo operator to compute the remainder of the division to obtain the last digit?

integer below

```
do {
    c[i++] = (char)(((int)'0')+(num %10 ));
} while ((num = (num/10)) != 0);
```

Comment: In C++, division of integral types always rounds toward zero.  Don't use `floor` unless you need it for floating-point operations (and even then, it can be tricky).

Comment: Oh ok I was not sure of that and he is using C not C++

Comment: Yeah I just removed floor as @aschepler said it is not mandoraty

Comment: It's not only not mandatory, it makes no sense in integer computations.  The compiler would convert the integer argument into a floating point argument, pass that to floor(), the result would be floating point, which the compiler would convert back to an integer before assigning it to the integer variable.  You should get exactly the same result, unless your original integer value's bit width was larger than the mantissa's bit width of your floating point type, in which case you'll now have the wrong result.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with C vs. C++.

Answer (score 0):

It isnt that it overflows, Ive tested it with this code.

```
unsigned long long num = 18446612134627563776;
char c[100];
unsigned int i = 0;

do {
    //print here
    c[i++] = '0'+ (char)(num - (num/10)*10 );
} while ((num = num/10) != 0);

c[i] = '\0';
cout << c << endl;
```

The problem is that the compiler is probably trying to use 10 as an int, and is having problems converting.  After putting the casting in, it actually works.  Problem is that the algorithm is backwards as it will bring in the 6, then the 7, etc...  The output is as follows from the above code which is exactly the same as his with the exception of the casting.

This is actual code, and actual output.

```
677365726431221664481
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Casting 10 as `unsigned long long` merely makes the compiler promote `num` to `unsigned long long` before the computation.  So in essence, you're doing the "same thing" as changing the type of `num` to  unsigned, but in the wrong way.  The compiler is not "having problems converting"... it's converting exactly according to the rules of promotion.

Comment: @phonetagger - You are correct, my tired mind just picked up on that. :-) It still will be backwards however. I promoted your answer LOL.